# Importing values from one window to another in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Suppose that I have a button in a window that when I click on it a new window will appear. I call this window (with the name of `My_New_Window`) with this syntax:

```
My_New_Window();
```

I want to insert some values to this new window from main window. I know that I can use `setappdata` or `getappdata` for this purpose but Is there another way to this? For example like this syntax:

```
My_New_Window(Values);
```

Another question. When we use `setappdata` or `getappdata`, where MATLAB stores this data? In the RAM or Hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use `My_New_Window(Values);` For example, in GUIDE, whatever parameters you pass to your GUI, you can handle in the `OpeningFcn` using its `varargin` input. Simply assign `varargin` to your `handles` structure and use `guidata(hObject, handles);`
2. Regarding `setappdata` - according to [this book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=fhpotPvv7v8C&pg=PA432&lpg=PA432&dq=matlab%20setappdata%20storage&source=bl&ots=2gd8Fn524p&sig=v4bZ-Enz9KwotmEUlbD-SX7AnRU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZbHXU4zdLYXAPMvWgIgP&redir_esc=y) the data is stored inside an "object". Since objects reside in memory, it is safe to assume that it is indeed kept in RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should use `guidata(hObject, handles);` after something like `My_New_Window(Values);` in main window. Is this true?

Comment: The procedure is 1) My_New_Window(Values); 2) (inside `My_New_Window_Opening_Fcn`): `handles.input=varargin` and `guidata(hObject, handles);` 3) If you need to access this data from some other callback, just use `handles.input`. Whenever you want to update the handles structure and save the result, you need to run `guidata(hObject, handles)` afterwards.

Comment: If 'varargin' was comma separated list of values what should I do ?

Comment: varargin is simply a cell array. You access its elements with varargin{idx}.

Comment: Another question related to this question. Suppose that now I want return some data from `My_New_Window` to `Main_Window` with your discussed method. What should I do?

Comment: Generally you should use `varargout` for this, but from what I remember, there was a difficulty associated with it. Here's a discussion on the topic, that should guide you in the right direction: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/145504

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in the GUI UserData property:

```
set(handletoFigure,'UserData',Values);
```

when you open the other GUI you retrieve the info:

```
Values = get(handletoFigure,'UserData);
```

Is there a reason why you don't want to use setappdata/getappdata?

As for your 2nd question I don't know sorry. I guess it's the RAM though

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I only want know other alternative or maybe faster methods to do this. Can we terminate this information like when we use `rmappdata` ? In your method is this data valid when we close main page (suppose that there is a prime window that we open main page from it)? can we call it from prime window?

Comment: Yes it should be removed using rmappdata. Also the data should not be valid when you close your main figure, since the handles to that figure won't exist anymore. My guess would be that storing application data in the root (eg. setappdata(0,'DataName',Data))are the safest way to make sure you can access your data when you close windows.