# Communication between two or more GUIs

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I've a GUI(i.e. lets call it 'First')through which i can choose to open other GUIs(let's call them 'Second' and 'Third').I want to put a 'pushbutton' on the 'First'GUI that allows me to manipulate the figure on the different axes of the 'Second' and 'Third' GUIs. So, i choose with the 'First'GUI if use either 'Second' or 'Third' GUI; once i've chosen that i start to work just with the GUI that i chose (so the Third one or Second ones). Now i want to have a pushbutton not on each GUIs (Second or Third) but only on the First one in order to manipulate the figure on the axes 1 of the Second or Third (depends on which one i've previously chosen). Furthermore this pushbutton that i want is optional and i need to refresh my axes after used that. 
I've done my best to explain the situation,please if you know any solution help me out!!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your question is similar to other examples, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017784/importing-values-from-one-window-to-another-in-matlab-gui/25018062?noredirect=1#comment38914249_25018062).

To understand how to solve your problem, you need to remember that MATLAB "decides" which axes to update based on the axes handle provided by the user. If the user doesn't provide a handle, a default `gca` (the *current axes*) is used. The axes that `gca` points to, is the first `child` of type `'axes'` of the figure, that is, the first entry in `findobj(hFigure,'Type','axes')`. You can read about setting the current axes [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/714-how-can-i-change-the-current-axes-in-a-gui).

Having established that, the solution you are looking for would involve storing the **axes handles** somewhere, and retrieving the correct one when you are about to update a plot. A common place to store it is the "application-defined data" (*appdata*), accessible by `setappdata` and `getappdata`, as mentioned in the first link above and also [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6831-updating-application-data-from-several-gui-s).

The procedure you should undergo is:

1. Upon creating a figure, store the axes handle in appdata by calling `setappdata(0,name,val)` (e.g. `setappdata(0,'axTag1',handles.axTag1)`) from your GUI initialization function. The value `0` for the 1st argument stores it in MATLAB's *root* object (you can think of it as the main MATLAB window), so that even if any of the figures is closed, the information is maintained as long as MATLAB is still open.
2. Whenever you want to modify an axes, just obtain the appropriate handle using `value = getappdata(0,name)` and use it to update the corresponding axes.